# Delamination vs stratification

Tags: world-english

Is there any difference between **delamination**  and **stratification** ?

Comment: Of course. The former starts with a "d", the latter with an "s".

Comment: @A.P. Not funny to someone with a rep of 1.

Comment: @deadrat I'm not sure rep has anything to do with it. These are fancy words. The person is presumably smart enough to be reading a text containing these, but then they can't google them? And ask about *any* difference? Anyway, this was merely my tongue-in-cheek attempt to show we need more context to meaningfully answer the question.

Comment: @A.P. Oh, I got it.  In fact, I've only just now stopped chuckling.  The person may indeed be smart enough to understand the topic, possibly in his native language.  I'm not sure that rep has anything to do with it either, but for newbies I like to err on the side of less clever word play.  Nothing is more opaque than humor to someone unsure of a language.

Comment: The **de-** prefix in the word **delamination**  means to undo or to reverse. Deforestation means to cut the trees down.  Destruction means to take down something that has been constructed.  Delouse means to get rid of lice.  Decant means to pour out of a bottle that which was put into it.

Comment: @TimRomano Thanks for pointing that out.  I've added the explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are opposites.  Both words come from Latin words for layer -- *stratum* and *lamina*.  *Stratification* means formation into layers; *delimination* is the process whereby the layers in a stratified substance separate.  (The [*de-*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=de-&searchmode=none) comes from the Latin prefix that signals an undoing of the verb sense that follows.)

For [instance](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1399371/), the skin is a **stratified** epithelial membrane that acts as a barrier to keep bodily fluids in and foreign substances out.  The bottom layer is formed of an inner layer basal cells that divide.  This layer continuously **delaminates**, migrates toward the surface, with the cells stopping their division on the way to forming the top, barrier layer.

For another [instance](https://books.google.com/books?id=6J7sCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA164&lpg=PA164&dq=Delamination%20vs%20stratification&source=bl&ots=yu_a8gVAFc&sig=JHL8N4PDv03Ii8KYDnHNw5_MFUM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBWoVChMI87Dp3tqHyQIVjNQmCh13lwKg#v=onepage&q=Delamination%20vs%20stratification&f=false), **laminated** beams for construction are formed by gluing together many layers of material.  Each layer is sometimes reinforced with glass fibers.  Of crucial interest to the construction industry is under what conditions the the layers will **deliminate**, i.e., separate, causing the beams to fail.  Apparently, the orientation of the reinforcing fibers in each layer is important.

Comment: Thanks, at first I thought they would be of the same meaning -- "分层" when I looked them up in bing dict, so I felt puzzled.

Comment: @Sandbro See TimRomano's comment, which I've incorporated into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In what context? If you're talking geology, then delamination refers to when layers of the lithosphere break apart (lower continental crust and the upper mantle below it, breaks away from upper continental crust). Stratification in geology is the layering in sedimentary rock, caused by deposition of particles over time.

Comment: Well, the original text: amorphous--devoid of crystallinity or stratification.  Then I thought of the word "Delamination" and could not tell them apart. My native language is Chinese, the Chinese translation of these 2 words are the same. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: @Sandbro - If the Chinese translation is the same for both then you need to get a new Chinese/English dictionary.